# How set text color of combobox?

Tags: javafx, combobox

I'm trying to set the text color of combobox.

[image]

My code, which I tried
`comboList.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: blue");`

Comment: As soon as I want to style a component I do not know I have a look on the default style sheet included in JavaFX 8 : [modena.css](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470#file-modena-css-L415). Look for Combobox component. If possible it is cleaner (and often easier) to set style of your components with your own css stylesheet.

Comment: it rarely helps to apply random styles - instead study the specification https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html and find out which styles are supported for which nodes

Answer (score 3):

Try it with

```
.combo-box .list-cell 
{
    -fx-background: white;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

[image]